# Jenkins test coverage report for JavaScript tests

Tags: javascript, testing, user-interface, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We run a CI environment with Jenkins and the Project is in ExtJS 3.2. I am not able to find a clear line on how to setup the test coverage for JS code in Jenkins. We write UI tests using selenium and Cucumber. The build file has a UI tests target which is run every time the CI machine runs a build. I am not able to find a plugin that will give me or publish the coverage report of these tests that have been run as a resulting atrifact in Jenkins.
Or please help me out if there is some other way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.com/JSCover/) to generate code coverage when using Selenium:

- Start JSCover java web service
- Let Selenium hit the JSCover web-app and start the collector, also see the [manual of JSCover](http://tntim96.github.com/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#automating) about automated tests.
- Run the Selenium tests in a new window or iFrame
- Collect the coverage data and store it somewhere
- Process the data into a nice report (possible with [genhtml](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php))

If you start a new browser for each Cucumber scenario/feature, then you need to save the coverage data between each scenario/feature, combine them after all features are done and then process them into a nice report. JSCover supports merging of multiple data sources and creating LCOV reports.

Comment: Updated the answer, found a possible solution. Going to see if I can get this to work soon, keep you posted.

Comment: Yes, we got this working in a proof of concept. Although I don't remember why we didn't integrate it into our continuous integration setup.